# Codependent/parent question type

Tags: forms, user-research, progressive-disclosure

I am having troubles finding useful information about codependent/parent question type, I will explain.

I am working on a Survey project and I need to create a question type with some logic added to it, for example:

- In a scale of 0 to 10 how much did you liked the breakfast?[image]

Then I need to add the logic, and there's many ways of doing it...

**IF** 0 to 5
**THEN** show following up/parent/codepending question type

Does it make sense to you? What I need is some help to find studies about this type of questions, but it's being super hard to find it.

Comment: It seems like you might be looking for help with survey software, and struggling to find the right help based on not knowing what the terms are called. Some words you might research are branching answers, or question logic.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you look into existing survey services and see how they handle this. Some popular ones are Google Forms, Microsoft Forms, Surveymonkey and others.

For example, this is from Google Forms. Once you select "go to section based on answer" in the bottom menu, the middle panel appears in the question box, where you can choose which option will each answer lead to.
[image]